# How do I create a GoogleCredential from an authorized access_token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, drive

I have an OAuth2 token like this...

```
{{
  "access_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "expires_in": "3600",
  "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
}}
```

and I'm trying to create a DriveService object...

```
Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "foo",
});
```

(like this?)

but I'm clearly not doing this properly and I'm having trouble finding documentation.

When I attempt to create a `GoogleCredential` to pass to the `DriveService`

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(credentialAsSerializedJson).CreateScoped(GoogleDriveScope);
```

I get the following exception:

**{System.InvalidOperationException: Error creating credential from JSON. Unrecognized credential type .**

Am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

(This is [the sample code context](https://github.com/dbelcher/TestXamAuthGoogleDrive/blob/master/TestXamAuthGoogleDrive/GoogleDriveAgent.cs#L163))

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#, but I think there is a guide for [OAuth 2.0 in C#](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) will help you create a driveService with an authorized access_token. This will also provide guide to differentiate User credentials and ServiceAccountCredential. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to do just the opposite. I have a `GoogleCredential` and I need to obtain an Access Token. Any ideas?

Comment: As per @jon-skeet 's comment in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75661327/c-sharp-get-credentials-from-google-sheets-api      >         try https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out.

The solution was to create a `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` with my ClientID and ClientSecret...

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow googleAuthFlow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer()
{
  ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
  {
    ClientId = ClientID,
    ClientSecret = ClientSecret,
  }
});
```

and also a `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse`:

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse responseToken = new TokenResponse()
{
  AccessToken = SavedAccount.Properties["access_token"],
  ExpiresInSeconds = Convert.ToInt64(SavedAccount.Properties["expires_in"]),
  RefreshToken = SavedAccount.Properties["refresh_token"],
  Scope = GoogleDriveScope,
  TokenType = SavedAccount.Properties["token_type"],
};
```

and use each to create a `UserCredential` that is, in turn, used to initialize the DriveService...

```
var credential = new UserCredential(googleAuthFlow, "", responseToken);

Service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
  HttpClientInitializer = credential,
  ApplicationName = "com.companyname.testxamauthgoogledrive",
});
```

I updated the [TestXamAuthGoogleDrive test harness project](https://github.com/dbelcher/TestXamAuthGoogleDrive/blob/master/TestXamAuthGoogleDrive/GoogleDriveAgent.cs#L169) to reflect these changes.

Comment: which type of application did you create in console? is it web, or other? because Android or Ios doesnt have client secret. did you use xamairn auth to get token?

Comment: You only need the refreshtoken in the new TokenResponse() which you can get in google playground.

Answer (score 0):

Working example at:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed-applications

The code will present the end user with an authorization page - where you have to log in with your google account and authorize the application to use the respective Google Service.