# How to use Google Apis using existing Access Token in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I implemented login process successfully in my Xamarin forms app using Xamarin.auth. now I want to connect to Google APIs and upload AppData. here is the Code I tried,
I tread to fetch the GoogleCredential using token and providing this Credential to Google API but it failed.

```
var store = AccountStore.Create();
                var SavedAccount = store.FindAccountsForService(GoogleDriveBackup.Auth.Constants.AppName).FirstOrDefault();


                GoogleCredential credential2 = GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken(SavedAccount.Properties["access_token"]);
                var driveService = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential2,
                    ApplicationName = "myApp",
                });
                FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
                var filePath = Path.Combine(path, filename);
                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath,
                    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                {
                    request = driveService.Files.Create(
                        fileMetadata, stream, "application/json");
                    request.Fields = "id";
                    request.Upload();
                }
                var file = request.ResponseBody;
```

request.ResponseBody is always null. I thought that it has something to do with credentials.

I tried using

```
  var store = AccountStore.Create();
            var SavedAccount = store.FindAccountsForService(GoogleDriveBackup.Auth.Constants.AppName).FirstOrDefault();


            var flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "xxxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                    ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxx"
                }
            });

            Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse responseToken = new Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse()
            {
                AccessToken = SavedAccount.Properties["access_token"],
                ExpiresInSeconds = Convert.ToInt64(SavedAccount.Properties["expires_in"]),
                RefreshToken = SavedAccount.Properties["refresh_token"],
                Scope = DriveService.Scope.DriveAppdata,
                TokenType = SavedAccount.Properties["token_type"],
            };
            var token= SavedAccount.Properties["access_token"];

            var credential = new UserCredential(flow, "", responseToken);
```

But above case requires Client Secret which I don't have as I created "Android App" in the google console and signed in using on ClientId. So I read somewhere that I should create "Others" in the google console and use ClientId and Client Secret from there which makes not much sense to me because I am logged in with different client id's. Anyway, I tried that also but the response was null.
So what is the deal here? How can achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google .net client library doesn't support xamarin.  I am actually surprised you got it working this far.   The main issue you are going to have is the authentication as you have already noticed the credential type for the .net client library is going to be either browser, native or api key.   The mobile (Android Ios) clients arnt going to work as you dont have a secret the method of authentication is different and the client library doesn't have ability to do this.

The only suggestion i would have would be to work out Oauth2 authentication with xamarin on your own and then build the TokenResponse as you are doing now.  You may then be able to feed that token to the Google .net client library if you can get the dlls into your project.

To my knowlage we have no plans to support xamarinwith the Google .net clinet library in the near future please see [984](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/984) [840](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/840) [1167](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1167)

Comment: thanks for your answer. i went through entire conversation and even linked once but they are talking about GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker which i know that not working. thats why i tried to avoid and create credential manually using my generated token. is that also not working? it confused me because there is this post and it claims that they achieved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44337136/how-do-i-create-a-googlecredential-from-an-authorized-access-token

Comment: he even have a test project using xamarin.ios and claims working https://github.com/dbelcher/TestXamAuthGoogleDrive/blob/master/TestXamAuthGoogleDrive/GoogleDriveAgent.cs#L169

Comment: It looks like hes using Xamarin.Auth and then linking it in to the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow he must have made web browser or native application credentials on google developer console.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve Appdata backup without using google api? maybe directly sending http post/patch request using HttpClient ?

Comment: sure you can do it all directly though normal HTTP POST and HTTP Get requests all the info you need is in the documentation.    Just send the access token you get from Xamarin.auth as a bearer token on all your requests.    I have done this before its really not that hard